# vertical flip bitmap in C doesn't work

Tags: c, bitmap, variable-assignment, flip

I'm having trouble with this bit of code.  Trying to vertically flip a 24-bit uncompressed bmp file with this method but getting segmentation fault.  I've gone over the logic and it seems to be right.  What do I have wrong?

```
int verticalflip (PIXEL *original, PIXEL **new, int rows, int cols) {

    int row, col;

    if ((rows <= 0) || (cols <= 0)) return -1;

    *new = (PIXEL*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(PIXEL));

    for (row=0; row < rows; row++)
        for (col=0; col < cols; col++) {
            PIXEL* o = original + row*cols + col;
            PIXEL* n = (*new) + (rows-1-row)*cols + col;
            *n = *o;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you passing as `new` in the function call?

Comment: It should be something like: `PIXEL* flipped; verticalflip(..., &flipped, ...);`

Comment: Passing PIXEL *bitmap, *newBitmap to original and new respectively.

I have another method to horizontally flip that is essentially the same, but with different logic of course, and that one works fine.

I think perhaps the issue is not in the logic of the function but somewhere else.  I'm checking my entire code all over.

Comment: Do you mean PIXEL **newBitmap?

Comment: My function call:

verticalflip(bmp, &newBmp, rows, columns);

Comment: Dillon thank you for the help.  I found the issue outside the function.  A missing break; statement in my switch to handle command line arguments.

I literally have been going over the logic for this function for 2 hours wondering why It made sense but wasn't working.

Comment: regarding: `*new = (PIXEL*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(PIXEL));  1)  the return type from `malloc()` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) ALWAYS check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when posting a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem

Comment: @ user3629249 thanks for the tip.

@ user3629249 Yeah sorry, this was my first posts.  Noted for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are trying to create a bitmap matrix,

```
*new = (PIXEL*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(PIXEL));
```

won't allocate memory correctly.

The code should be:

```
new = malloc(rows*sizeof(PIXEL*));
for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
    new[i] = (PIXEL*)malloc(cols*sizeof(PIXEL));
```

`rows` and `cols` can be switched depending on the rest of your logic.

Comment: Not correct.  A bit map in an image is contiguous memory, not a array of pointers to pixels

Comment: That may be the case, but the data structure used to represent the bitmap does not matter. I've accessed and operated on bitmaps using matrices without any problems.